# How to change the Estimate values from lmer() or lm() function in R?

Tags: r, lme4, summary

I used lmer() and summ() to output the Est values for each feature. However, I want to take log of all the Est values and output the same table. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you want to log values of coefficients which could be negative. However, it can be done. This is a tidyverse way: `broom::tidy(mod) %>% mutate(estimate = log(estimate))`. It will give NaN when you have negative values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zhiqiang, I got an error message of Error in broom::tidy(mod) : object 'mod' not found, when I use the code. How do I fix this?

Comment: It is your model name. You can use whatever name your model is. `mod<-lm(ROLL ~UNEW, data = datavar)`

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang, please post as answer? (and note that they will need `library(tidyverse); library(broom); library(broom.mixed)`).

Comment: Can you please post your summary example as text rather than as an image? I realize that makes it harder to highlight the estimates you're interested in transforming, but it is easier to search and accessible to screen readers.

Comment: PS `mutate(across(estimate, log))` is slightly more compact.

Comment: It would be helpful for others to give a testable answer if an reproducible example were added in OP

Comment: @BenBolker I would be happy to try an answer if a reproducible example is provided in OP.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
(mod
   |> tidy()
   |> mutate(across(estimate, log))
)
```

should work, where `mod` is the variable holding the fitted model. This will give warnings and `NaN` values if any of the coefficient estimates are negative. (The standard error column will also be potentially misleading.)